# Is that even possible to decode Protobuf binary message to human readable view from Mysql blob column using only Mysql?

Tags: mysql, protocol-buffers

We store a protobuf messages using:

```
...
payload.toByteArray(),
...
```

into a `longblob` column and normally we read them out in a Spring-based application and do handling there.

However, there is a quite straightforward question: is it possible to read those longblob column values just within a SQL query (probably using a stored procedure) avoiding loading data into the application and handling it there?

We need that converter only for one particular message type structure:

```
message Entry
{
   int64 time = 1;
   repeated Point points = 2;
}
message Point
{
   uint64 status = 1;
   int64 value = 2;
   google.protobuf.Timestamp timestamp = 3;
}
```

Personally I don't see any possible solution here, however, maybe it's because I don't have enough experience with protobuf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL stored procedures do have all the necessary programming constructs to do this, so theoretically it is possible. However, it will involve quite a bit of programming and is probably not worth doing on database side.

However, here is the rough sketch of what the stored procedures would have to do. Refer to [Protobuf encoding documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding) for details.

1. Create a stored procedure `read_varint()` that will read the first `varint` from a blob, and returns it as integer and the remaining blob.
2. Create a stored procedure `decode_point()` that repeatedly calls `read_varint()` to take a tag, then calls `read_varint()` to read field data and assigns it to variable based on tag number.
3. Create similar `decode_timestamp()` for the built-in `google.protobuf.Timestamp` datatype and call it from `decode_point()` for the timestamp field.
4. Create a stored procedure `decode_entry()` that repeatedly calls `read_varint()` to take a tag, and either decodes `time` directly or calls `decode_point()`, depending on the tag value.
5. Extend all these procedures to skip fields with unknown tag numbers.

Interestingly, your message types only have `varint` fields. So at the bare minimum, you could just call `read_varint()` repeatedly to get all the varints to a list. Then each field is always at a specific index. However, I don't recommend this, because it wouldn't be possible to extend it to handle future fields of different types.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the given sketch. Actually that is I wanted to say: the encoding/decoding algorithm is enough sophisticated.